# Understanding imports and exports in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

In Webpack, I can call `var path = require('path');`. Does that mean Webpack runs on top of Node.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Webpack runs on Node.js. You run the `webpack` command using Node.js from the command line, and this generates a bundle containing your JavaScript, your CSS, and other static assets such as images (depending on how your build is configured). You then use that generated bundle file in your web page or app, away from Node.JS and in the browser.

This is different from tools like SystemJS, which does a similar job, but runs in the browser instead of Node.js. SystemJS can also include files that use `var x = require('something')`, but it handles these imports using RequireJS rather than Node.